# Is there any way to find summation of first n perfect numbers?

Tags: number-theory

I was studying properties of perfect numbers when this question clicked me.
Is there any way to find summation of first n perfect numbers?

Is the only way to sum them up is to write them down?

Sorry if my question is too vague but I'm really curious to know as you all are like my teachers.

Comment: A form for the sum of the first $n$ perfect numbers easily leads to a form for the $n$th perfect number. It is still open whether there are infinitely many perfect numbers, or whether any of them are odd, so it's extremely likely there is no easy answer here.

Comment: Has anyone proved/disapproved existance of infinite perfect numbers sir @anon ?

Comment: I would certainly approve of an infinity of perfect numbers.

Comment: The existence of infinitely many perfect numbers is as yet neither proved nor disproved.